# Conditional formatting over huge range in excel, using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have an excel workbook that has about 30k rows in a given column. I need to cross validate another equally huge list to see if there are any matches. If so, then I want it to highlight that cell.

As suggested in other threads, I recorded the macro manually and the code is:

```
Sheets("Main").Select
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlTextString, String:= _
    "=list1!$A$1", TextOperator:=xlContains
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

This macro works but only for the first cell in the other sheet that contains the huge list I want to validate. However, I can't get it to work for the other 49999 rows. Moreover, this list is in another sheet.

I tried creating a for loop, like `for i = 1 to length of column`, do *this* but failed miserably every time.

Comment: You can create a formula that checks all the rows in the indexing sheet. That's what user3598756's answer does using the `COUNTIF` formula. You could use the same formula in a helper column of your main sheet, wrapping it in an `IF` formula to return either TRUE (Countif returns 1 or more) or FALSE (Countif returns 0). This is what I had thought was meant by "non-CF" in that answer. This would let you filter by TRUE/FALSE rather than by color, which might be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited** after OP's question about CF approach versus other ones

**edited2**: added "dictionary" approach

"Conditional formatting" approach can be quicker than the "Range" one, but the former can also make worksheet very *heavy* and *slow* in subsequent use.
not to mention I also had crash down experiences after too many CF cells

"Dictionary" approach is both quickest

here follow possible codes for all above mentioned approaches

---

**"CF" approach**

If you *really* **must** use conditional formatting and if I correctly undestood your aim, then try this (commented) code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim mainRng As Range, list1Rng As Range

    Set mainRng = GetRange(Worksheets("Main"), "D") '<--| get "Main" sheet column "D" range from row 1 down to last non empty row
    Set list1Rng = GetRange(Worksheets("list1"), "A") '<--| get "list1" sheet column "D" range from row 1 down to last non empty row

    AddCrossCountFormatCondition mainRng, list1Rng '<--| add cross validation from "Main" to "List1" worksheet
    AddCrossCountFormatCondition list1Rng, mainRng '<--| add cross validation from "List1" to "Main" worksheet

End Sub

Function GetRange(ws As Worksheet, colIndex As String) As Range
    With ws '<--| reference passed worksheet
        Set GetRange = .Range(colIndex & "1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp)) '<--| set its column "colIndex" range from row 1 down to last non empty row
    End With
End Function

Sub AddCrossCountFormatCondition(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range)
    With rng1
        Intersect(rng1.Parent.UsedRange, rng1.Resize(1, 1).EntireColumn).FormatConditions.Delete '<--| remove previous conditional formatting
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
            "=COUNTIF(" & rng2.Parent.Name & "!" & rng2.Address & ",concatenate(""*""," & rng1.Resize(1, 1).Address(False, False) & ",""*""))>0"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**"Range" approach**

```
Option Explicit

Sub main2()
    Dim mainRng As Range, list1Rng As Range

    Set mainRng = getRange(Worksheets("Main"), "D") '<--| get "Main" sheet column "D" range from row 1 down to last non empty row
    Set list1Rng = getRange(Worksheets("list1"), "A") '<--| get "list1" sheet column "D" range from row 1 down to last non empty row

    ColorMatchingRange mainRng, list1Rng
    ColorMatchingRange list1Rng, mainRng

End Sub

Sub ColorMatchingRange(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range)
    Dim unionRng As Range, cell As Range, f As Range

    Set unionRng = rng1.Offset(, rng1.Columns.Count).Resize(1, 1)
    For Each cell In rng1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, "*" & cell.Value & "*") > 0 Then Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, cell)
    Next cell
    Set unionRng = Intersect(unionRng, rng1)
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
        With unionRng.Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Function getRange(ws As Worksheet, colIndex As String) As Range
    With ws '<--| reference passed worksheet
        Set getRange = .Range(colIndex & "1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp)) '<--| set its column "colIndex" range from row 1 down to last non empty row
    End With
End Function
```

---

**"Dictionary" approach**

```
Option Explicit

Sub main3()
    Dim mainRng As Range, list1Rng As Range
    Dim mainDict As New Scripting.Dictionary, list1Dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

    Set mainRng = getRange(Worksheets("Main"), "D") '<--| get "Main" sheet column "D" range from row 1 down to last non empty row
    Set list1Rng = getRange(Worksheets("list1"), "A") '<--| get "list1" sheet column "D" range from row 1 down to last non empty row

    Set mainDict = GetDictionary(mainRng)
    Set list1Dict = GetDictionary(list1Rng)

    ColorMatchingRange2 mainRng, mainDict, list1Dict
    ColorMatchingRange2 list1Rng, list1Dict, mainDict

End Sub

Sub ColorMatchingRange2(rng1 As Range, dict1 As Scripting.Dictionary, dict2 As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Dim unionRng As Range
    Dim vals As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    vals = Application.Transpose(rng1.Value)

    Set unionRng = rng1.Offset(, rng1.Columns.Count).Resize(1, 1)
    For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
        If dict2.Exists(vals(i)) Then Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, rng1(i, 1))
    Next i

    Set unionRng = Intersect(unionRng, rng1)
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
        With unionRng.Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Function GetDictionary(rng As Range) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim vals As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    vals = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
        dict.Add vals(i), rng(i, 1).Address
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set GetDictionary = dict
End Function

Function getRange(ws As Worksheet, colIndex As String) As Range
    With ws '<--| reference passed worksheet
        Set getRange = .Range(colIndex & "1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp)) '<--| set its column "colIndex" range from row 1 down to last non empty row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will test this possibility very soon. You said **must**, but is there another way to highlight cells if there is a match? The problem is that I can't create a rule of conditional formatting that goes through all rows in the indexing sheet. It has to be one by one and well... There will be 30k rows to go one by one...

Comment: see edited answer. if my answer fulfilled your question please mark it as accepted. thank you

Comment: **CF Approach**: It also changes and highlights first row, which should be the table header. Moreover, it also highlights on the other sheet. Only needed it to mark the "main" tab.
**Range approach**: It does not change the table header but also highlights the other sheet.
**Dictionary approach**: This row `Sub ColorMatchingRange2(rng1 As Range, dict1 As Scripting.Dictionary, dict2 As Scripting.Dictionary` outputs the error `User-defined type not defined`.

Thanks!!

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you could help me fixing the double highlighting issue, by the way.

Comment: I'm not by Pc so some are nearly blind shots.  1) CF approach: comment out 2nd "AddCrossCountFormatCondition" call 2) Dictionary approach: comment out 2nd "ColorMatchingRange2" call and add  "Microsoft Scripting Library" (or very similar) library reference to your project

Comment: Still outputs the same error. Also, do you think you can fix the Range approach? That seems just right and not too heavy to be processed.

Comment: Same errors? Look, commenting out the 2nd `AddCrossCountFormatCondition` call in `Sub Main()` or the 2nd `ColorMatchingRange ` call in `Sub main2()` or the 2nd `ColorMatchingRange2 ` call in `Sub main3()` _DO_ have the effect 
of eliminating the double checking. AND, adding reference to _Microsoft Scripting Library_ library (Menu Tools->References and check the proper listbox entry) to your project _DOES_ have the effect of correcting the `User-defined type not defined` error

Comment: Apologies for not keep testing. I decided to go with another method that wouldn't use VBA. Damn this hold stuff is slow :) Thanks though!