# Conditional formatting/testing headers against prescribed header list (Excel-VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I use VBA rarely and am always re-learning. This is my first posting.

I am using OCR to pull in tables from PDFs to individual worksheets (usually 100-200 tabs) and I have VBA programming ready to consolidate the data based on header values. But the headers are error prone and need to be reviewed first. I want to run a VBA macro that tests headers in row 1 against a set list and highlight those headers that exactly match.

I found a great start with [Conditional formatting over huge range in excel, using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436603/conditional-formatting-over-huge-range-in-excel-using-vba) (Dictionary Approach) which tests lists, but I am struggling to convert the code to handle rows instead of columns. (Next I plan to have it run on every tab in the workbook, but am stuck at the testing stage).

Here is my current edit of the original code to pull from rows, but I get a subscript out of range on `If dict2.Exists(vals(i)) Then`

```
Option Explicit

Sub main3()
    Dim mainRng As Range, list1Rng As Range
    Dim mainDict As New Scripting.Dictionary, list1Dict As New 
    Scripting.Dictionary   'Main is Header and list1 is prescribed header list

    Set mainRng = GetRange(Worksheets("Main"), "1") '<--| get "Main" sheet row "1" range from column A right to last non empty column
    Set list1Rng = GetRange(Worksheets("list1"), "1") '<--| get "list1" sheet row "1" range from column A right to last non empty column

    Set mainDict = GetDictionary(mainRng)
    Set list1Dict = GetDictionary(list1Rng)

    ColorMatchingRange2 list1Rng, list1Dict, mainDict

End Sub

Sub ColorMatchingRange2(rng1 As Range, dict1 As Scripting.Dictionary, dict2 As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Dim unionRng As Range
    Dim vals As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    vals = rng1.Value 'oringinal code transposed with = Application.Transpose(rng1.Value)

    Set unionRng = rng1.Offset(rng1.Rows.Count).Resize(1, 1)
    For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
        If dict2.Exists(vals(i)) Then Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, rng1(1, i))
    Next i

    Set unionRng = Intersect(unionRng, rng1)
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
        With unionRng.Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Function GetDictionary(rng As Range) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim vals As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    vals = rng.Value 'oringinal code transposed with=Application.Transpose(rng.Value)

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
        dict.Add vals(i), rng(1, i).Address
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set GetDictionary = dict
End Function
Function GetRangeRow(ws As Worksheet, rowIndex As String) As Range
    With ws '<--| reference passed worksheet
        Set GetRangeRow = .Range("A" & rowIndex, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) '<--| set its row "rowIndex" range from row 1 right to last non empty column
    End With
End Function
```

More background, the VBA will be in a Control Workbook with the set header list, and the code will run on the ActiveWorkbook which will be the data across many worksheets, but I believe I've got that figured out.

Comment: You can use Match() to test each header against your list of valid values and highlight the matches.  If you could post what you've tried you're more likely to get suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @Tim I've posted my edit of the original dictionary code

Answer (score 1):

Simpler approach:

```
Sub HighlightMatchedHeaders()

    Dim rngList As Range, c As Range, v
    Dim sht As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'or whatever
    'set the lookup list
    With wb.Sheets("list")
        Set rngList = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
        'ignore the "list" sheet
        If sht.Name <> rngList.Worksheet.Name Then
            'checking row 1
            For Each c In Application.Intersect(sht.Rows(1), sht.UsedRange).Cells
                v = Trim(c.Value)
                If Len(v) > 0 Then
                    'has a header: check for match
                    If Not IsError(Application.Match(v, rngList, 0)) Then
                        c.Interior.Color = vbRed 'show match
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next sht

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this is perfect and I can understand the code very well. The code ran on my sample workbook without any noticeable lag. Thank you @Tim !